# Программа, которая выводит на экран первую часть таблицы кодировки символов

Tags: c, c++

Привет всем, помогите пожалуйста с задачай. **Условие :** Написать программу, которая выводит на экран первую часть таблицы кодировки символов (символы с кодами от 0 до 127). Таблица должна состоять из восьми колонок и шестнадцати строк. В первой колонке должны быть символы с кодом от 0 до 15, во второй — от 16 до 31 и т.д. **Вот код :**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, m, n;
    cout << "Stroki : ";  cin >> m;
    cout << "Stolbci : "; cin >> n;
    cout << "ASCII\n";
    char** table = new char* [m];
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        table[i] = new char[n];
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            table[i][j] = (n*i + j);
            cout << table[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Но он выводит **только ASCII символы**, а мне нужно чтобы выводило **символы с кодами** от 0 до 127.

Comment: @battlemanls, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: а мне интересно, как символ кодом 13 вы собрались посмотреть?

Comment: @battlemanls: посмотрите на `isprint`. А вообще, задача тривиальная, зачем вам промежуточная таблица?

Comment: @battlemanls, Вы же сами пишите:

"выводит на экран первую часть таблицы **кодировки символов**",

а выводите *символы*.

Вот кодировки и выводите. Например, 16-ричные:

    вложенные циклы по сторкам и столбцам
        printf ("%02x%c", простая-формула-из-номеров-строки-и-столбца, последний-в-столбце ? '\n' : ' ');

Answer (score 1):

Этот код Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
тут вроде надо лишь убрать std:: и все должно работать... отпишись когда проверишь...
у меня вроде работает)))

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{         
    short mass [16][8] = {0};
    short ii(0);
    char buk(0);

    for (short j=0; j<= 7; j++)
    {

        for (short i=0; i<= 15; i++)
        {
            mass[i][j] = ii;
            ii++;
        }
    }
    for (short i=0; i<= 15; i++)
        {
            for (short j=0; j<= 7; j++)
            {
            buk = (mass[i][j]);
            std::cout<<buk<<"  ";
            }
            std::cout<<'\n';
        }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: >Этот код Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

что конкретно здесь имеет отношение к Visual Studio?

Comment: А то, что компилятор DEV не принял такое написание std::cout... Ошибка была. Конечно, может я не совсем разобрался просто... Написал на всякий случай... Мешает?

Comment: Да как вам сказать - у вас множество логических ошибок, вы путаете компилятор и IDE, утверждаете, что самое обычное пространство имен **std** является майкрософтовской фичей (а на самом-то деле вы просто забыли импортировать этот неймспейс, благодаря чему cout не работает), и тем  самым даете безграмотный и неправильный совет, который может ввести в заблуждение кого-то неопытного, и который, кстати.

Comment: Вы правы, конечно. Во первых, я не заметил с самого начала using namespace std;, так как, я не просматривал код этого человека, для меня проще свой написать. 
Эта строчка позволяет не писать std::, я знаю)). Во вторых, я не очень опытный программист, когда начал программировать с помощью DEV, было много ошибок, и я отказался от него.. Перешел на Visual Studio. Поэтому, я ошибся и сказал глупость. Надеюсь, вы простите меня!!!  
Код то работает? Или я ошибся?

Comment: @pashaha, а зачем вам массив? (у ТС спросили уже, кстати) и два одинаковых цикла? так можно писать после знакомства с главной циклы и массивы в какой-нить книжке с картинками... "тем самым даете безграмотный и неправильный совет, который может ввести в заблуждение кого-то неопытного" (c) @DreamChild.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov . Можете подать пример мне и написать программу лучше чем у меня) Я написал так, как знал. Наверно вовсе не стоило отвечать на вопрос) Больше не буду) Напишите пожалуйста ваш вариант программы... Грамотный вариант) У меня есть возможность поучиться у более опытного программиста. Раз вы так раскритиковали мою программу) Сделайте одолжение) И таким образом я лучше пойму свою ошибку...

Comment: @pashaha, ваше стремление помочь понятно и приветствуется. и то, что вы ответили и увидели критику, пойдет вам на пользу, поверьте. однако, вы не ответили на вопросы. они были не критикующими, а наводящими. поймите, именно с таких задач и начинается обучение. Пробуйте, ошибайтесь, снова пробуйте.  
вот вам [пример на Javascript'е](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/HV4Dp/) для размышления.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, Спасибо! С удовольствием посмотрю ваш код...))